# Toast Inside Fragment Not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-toast

I have fragment in that fragment i am try to call Toast when user enter wrong Login and Password but Toast is not visible when login button is pressed and log above toast is calling but still toast is not visible

[image: This is my Fragment]

**Here is my fragment**

```
public class Login_Fragment extends Fragment {

    EditText LoginUname,LoginPass;
    ImageButton SignIn;
    Context context;
    public static final String TAG="Login Fragment";


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment,container,false);
        LoginUname= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Login_Box);
        LoginPass= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Pass_Box);
        SignIn= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.LoginButton);

        SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String Phone=LoginUname.getText().toString();
                String Password=LoginPass.getText().toString();

                new AsyncTask(){
                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                        Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result: "+result); //GETTING RESULT FAIL HERE

                        if (result.equals("FAIL")){
                            Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result is FAIL"); //THIS LOG SHOWING IN LOGCAT BUT TOAST IS NOT VISIBLE 
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid Login And Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                        else if (result.equals("SUCCESS")){
                            Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result is Success");

                        }

                    }
                }.execute();
                Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","----LOGIN AND PASSWORD SENT");

            }
        });
        Registration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Registration_Fragment registrationFragment=new Registration_Fragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.FragmentLoginRegistration,registrationFragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context=context;
    }
}
```

**Log**

```
08-23 14:04:38.115 29053-29053/com.boysjoys.com.pro_working1 D/LOGIN FRAGMENT: Result: FAIL
08-23 14:04:38.115 29053-29053/com.boysjoys.com.pro_working1 D/LOGIN FRAGMENT: Result is FAIL
```

i have already tried

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid Login And Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Login And Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


Toast.makeText(Login_Fragment.this.getActivity(), "Invalid Login And Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and almost all method i can use to show toast visible and at last i tried `runOnUiThread` but its still not showing.

**EDIT 1:** Added Log to show that i am getting response from server- "FAIL"

**Edit 2:** I tried every answer i got but my Toast still not showing up.So is there any chance that my manifest,layout blocks Toast to comes up? if Yes please let me know so i will update my layout,Style,Manifest in my question

Comment: As I see your code you are not initializaing the `SignIn` `Button`.

Comment: add your logs too so we can track the issue.

Comment: Does your Async Task gives result as FAIL or SUCCESS ??

Comment: post xml R.layout.login_fragment I will give you answer how to initialize SignIn button

Comment: But why are you using in `getActivity().runOnUiThread` . `onPostExecute()` method itself update `UI`.

Comment: @Stallion i already initialize all buttons i cut the code to understand where i am getting problem

Comment: U don't need to use _runOnUiThread_ @androidXP

Comment: @Ironman added complete code

Comment: @PiyushGupta i know but when nothing is working i have to try this

Comment: @androidXP Yes do that. It will work sure. Also must be sure that you'r getting response as a `"FAIL"` and `"SUCCESS"` from your server

Comment: @PiyushGupta you can check logcat

Answer (score 0):

getActivity() will return null if run before onAttach(Activity). Instead, you should call getActivity() directly in your onPreExecute and onPostExecute methods or get a reference to it in onAttach:

```
public void onAttach (Activity attachedActivity) {
    activity = attachedActivity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method at last or in app activity and call where you want its working

```
public void showToast(@NonNull String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: No. Its not related with OP's question

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is working fine for me. I have hardcoded the login Fail in doInBackground so that it should go inside the onPostExecute() login fail block. Here is the code

```
 new AsyncTask(){
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
                    return "FAIL"; // Hardcoded to make login fail
                }

                @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result: "+result);

                if (result.equals("FAIL")){
                    Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result is FAIL");
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result is FAIL 2");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid Login Or Password toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
                else if (result.equals("SUCCESS")){
                    Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result is Success");

                }

            }
        }.execute();
```

Comment: As you can see updated question i also post screenshot and also i post logcat but for me its not working at all i don't know what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should call show Toast on **UI Thread**, So just try like this:

```
SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String Phone=LoginUname.getText().toString();
            String Password=LoginPass.getText().toString();

            new AsyncTask(){
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result: "+result); //GETTING RESULT FAIL HERE

                    if (result.equals("FAIL")){
                        Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result is FAIL"); //THIS LOG SHOWING IN LOGCAT BUT TOAST IS NOT VISIBLE 
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid Login And Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    else if (result.equals("SUCCESS")){
                        Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result is Success");

                    }

                }
            }.execute();
            Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","----LOGIN AND PASSWORD SENT");

        }
    });
```

Comment: i already tried this by `runOnuithread` but no luck and also by your method

Comment: @androidXP I have test this in my local demo, it worked. So if it is OK for you to show the entire code?

Comment: Sure i will try again and revert to you soon

Answer (score 0):

**I recommended you take the Asynctask Call like that**

```
public class Login_Fragment extends Fragment {

EditText LoginUname,LoginPass;
ImageButton SignIn;
Context context;
public static final String TAG="Login Fragment";


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment,container,false);
    LoginUname= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Login_Box);
    LoginPass= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Pass_Box);
    SignIn= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.LoginButton);
 SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String Phone=LoginUname.getText().toString();
            String Password=LoginPass.getText().toString();

              new Asynctask(Phone,Password).execute();

        }
    });

  Registration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Registration_Fragment registrationFragment=new    Registration_Fragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction    transaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
              transaction.replace(R.id.FragmentLoginRegistration,registrationFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
 }

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context=context;
}




 private class Asynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {


 String password,phone;

        public Asynctask(String phone, String password) {
            password=password;
            phone=phone;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {

       // you need to take doInbackground to return result
            return "SUCCESS";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

          Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result: "+result);

            if (result.equals("FAIL")){
                Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result is FAIL");
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result is FAIL 2");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid Login Or Password toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }
            else if (result.equals("SUCCESS")){
                Log.d("LOGIN FRAGMENT","Result is Success");

            }


        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: Its separate class but i am calling onPostexecute in fragment because i wanted to fetch result and when success i am getting user details so i need to use it like that

Comment: that code is just to test answer below i remove it already sorry for confusion

Comment: i m calling like tht but only onPost i m calling in fragment i think it doesnt make any difference even it help me to transfer result in fragment without any additional code

Comment: i am executing doinbackground in separate class from that i am getting result in onPostexecute in fragment